# Is this set dense in [0,+∞)?

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis, abc-conjecture

We define $A=\{ \frac{c}{rad(abc)}: a, b > 0, c=a+b, gcd(a, b)=1 \}$.
Is the set $A$ dense in $[0, +\infty)$?
Does $\overline{A}$ have interior? Here $\overline{A}$ is the closure of $A$.

A well-known fact is that $\inf A=0$ and $\sup A=+\infty$.

Comment: The only accumulation point I can come up with (besides $0$ and $\infty$) is $1/2$ by using taking $a=1$ and $b$ a Mersenne prime, but conditional on there being infinitely many such primes. I plotted the ratios for all $abc$-triples below $10^18 (https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~desmit/abc/abctriples_below_1018.gz) and found no noticeable gaps (until the tail end). Last, I plotted the ratios for all triples $a+b=c$ for $c\le  10^5$ and ratio $<1$ - and found a few small gaps approaching $1$, the most noticeable a gap of size $>0.013$ centered near $0.87$ - but is that significant?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a full answer, but a pair of soft arguments suggesting that $A$ is dense in $[0, +\infty)$.

---

**First Argument**

Given any triple $(a,b,c)$, let $\displaystyle r(a,b,c)=\frac{c}{\text{rad}(abc)}$.
One can generate two new triples

$$t_1=(a(c+b),b^2,c^2)$$
$$t_2=(a^2,b(c+a),c^2)$$
with ratios
$$r(t_1)=r(a,b,c)\cdot\frac{c}{c+b}\cdot\frac{c+b}{\text{rad}(c+b)}$$
$$r(t_2)=r(a,b,c)\cdot\frac{c}{c+a}\cdot\frac{c+a}{\text{rad}(c+a)}$$

Clearly $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}<\frac{c}{c+a}, \frac{c}{c+b}<1$.
On the other hand $\displaystyle \frac{n}{\text{rad}(n)}$ is *on multiplicative average* equal to $\prod_{p} p^{1/(p^2-p)}\approx2.128$. So the tree of triples generated by repeated application of the transformations above,  will form paths of ratios that drift (mostly slowly) to increasingly higher values.
$0$ being an obvious accumulation point of $A$, one has infinitely many starting points for the process above, making it plausible that any presumed gap in $A$ will be cut by infinitely many paths.

---

**Second Argument**

This is via an example specifically targeting the gap around $0.87$ that was mentioned in a comment to the question. Start by approximating $0.87$ with a rational with squarefree denominator (and preferably multiple small prime factors). $61/70$ is a good candidate. Take the triple $(1, 2^{100}\cdot 5^7\cdot 7^4, 2^{100}\cdot 5^7\cdot 7^4+1)$ where the exponents $100,7,4$ are picked so that $61^2$ divides $c$. There is then a good chance that $c/\text{rad}(c)=61$, which is indeed the case here, and the ratio of the triple is therefore $61/70$.

Comment: Thanks for your discussions. 本问题只是抛砖引玉，还请各位志士仁人洒潘江、倾陆海。

Comment: I conjecture that even the subset of $A$ derived from triples with $a=1$ is dense in $[0,+\infty)$.

Comment: By looking at all Pythagorean triples with $c$ up to $637460^2$ I conjecture that that subset of $A$ too has ratios dense in the positive reals.